# How to group list of items by columns and rows using C#

Tags: c#

Say I have a list of values, like 1,2,3,4,5,6. I want to present these in an HTML table so that the items go down by each row in the first column, then start on the next column and go down by rows again. What I'm trying to build is a function that I can pass an IEnumerable of `<T>` along with a number of columns and it would generate a `List<List<T>>`, or list of rows, each containing the list of columns.

```cs
@{
    //ex: example of how I plan to use the function in a Razor file
    var list = Enumerable.Range(1, 6);
    var rows = list.ToRowCols(colCount:4);
}
<table border='1'>
    @foreach (var row in rows)
    {
        <tr>
            @foreach (var value in row)
            {
                <td>@value</td>
            }
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

The output would then look like this:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td>2</td>
         <td>4</td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I got pretty far with this function that I wrote, but it puts 6 in the third cell on the second row, instead of the fourth cell on the first row.

```cs
public static List<List<T>> ToRowCols<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int colCount)
{
    if (source == null || colCount == 0)
        return new List<List<T>>();

    var list = source.ToList();
    var rowCount = (int)Math.Ceiling(list.Count / (decimal)colCount);

    var rows = Enumerable.Range(1, rowCount)
        .Select(_ => Enumerable.Range(1, colCount)
            .Select(_ => default(T))
            .ToList())
        .ToList();

    var row = -1;
    var col = -1;
    foreach (var (item, index) in list.Select((item, index) => (item, index)))
    {
        if (index % rowCount == 0)
        {
            col++;
            row = 0;
        }

        rows[row][col] = item;
        row++;
    }

    return rows;
}
```

I know this probably sounds like a homework assignment or brain teaser, but it really isn't (I'll be using it to display a list of items with checkboxes :) I normally love writing fun, reusable library functions like this, but kinda got stumped on this one. I'm hoping there's some sort of solved algorithm that does this that this self-taught guy has just never heard of. Extra points if your answer uses LINQ to do it instead of a loop.

Comment: You need to compute number of full columns too for rows {2,rowCount}... Using slghtly bigger numbers should give you better idea what you want - like 21 item in 10 columns...

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding why 6 shouldn't end up in the 3rd cell of the second row according to your behavior requirement.

Comment: Why 3rd and 4th cell are empty in second row?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya the goal looks like to have given number (4 in the example) of non-empty columns - so first row must be filled completely. This leaves only 2 items to fill columns in the second row.  Since filling by column first two columns endup filled, third/forth with only one element: 1/2, 3/4,5/_, 6,_.

Comment: @W.Winnie explanations does not seem to exactly align with the desired HTML. Based on desired result it looks like OP wants all columns to have at least one element.